# Crashed while saving,core data in private context

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

My App Crashed while saving in core data in private context

Here is the crash report:

```
Crashed: Server Update Queue :: NSOperation 0x15ee4be0 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)
```

Comment: I have no idea how this question received an up vote.  It shows no research effort, and is neither useful nor clear.  @praveenraj - Please provide more information about your error.  Maybe some code from the NSOperation causing the crash, maybe a bigger stack trace, maybe a picture of the second shooter on the grassy knoll.  Barring any other information, I'd say you are accessing your context outside the confines of `performBlock`.

Comment: I have a nsoperation queue named"Server Update Queue" from the main thread and have added few operations to it.And when it saves in core data the app crashes.yes i have not wrapped it inside the perform block while saving.

Comment: Show the code and the stack trace